# CSS only accordian with input - hidden hyperlinks appearing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, accordion

I've built a CSS only accordian...  (And I specifically have been asked to build this without JavaScript).

So far my code is working fine. And I'm using the `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />` to achieve this.

The problem I am having, is that the content I am hiding/toggling, includes hyperlinks.  And when my accordian is closed, the hyperlinks are still clickable, even with the accordian is closed.

IE - if you were to hover 40px-50px under the copy "Choose another cool destination", you can't see the content. But you can still hover over the (invisible) hyperlinks. And even click them.

How can I stop this from happening?

I don't want my hyperlinks to be clickable. Only when the accordian is open!

Here is a codepen where you can see this:
https://codepen.io/ReenaVerma1981/pen/qBdbbWJ

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;

}

.readme {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ff6600;
    font-family: "easyjet_rounded_demi",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.accordion {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.accordion__item {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.accordion__item span {
    color: #ff6600;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 280px;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.accordion__item input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
.accordion__item input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.panel {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
            transform: translate(0, 50%);
}

.accordion__item input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ span {
    padding-top: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion__item input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span {
    padding-top: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.panel {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="accordion">
        <ul class="">
            <li class="accordion__item">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                <p class="readme">Choose another   cool destination</p>           
                <span class="">
                    <svg viewBox="1 1 22 22" width="1em" height="1em" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="icon-svg"><path d="M21.7 6.79a1 1 0 00-1.41 0L12 15.08 3.71 6.79a1 1 0 00-1.41 0 1 1 0 000 1.42l9 9a1 1 0 001.42 0l9-9a1 1 0 00-.02-1.42z"></path></svg>
                </span>
                <div class="panel">
                    <strong>
                        <a href="www.google.com">London</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">NYC</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">LA</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">LAX</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">Dublin</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">Liverpool</a>,
                        <a href="www.google.com">Manchester</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">Dubai</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">Hong Kong</a>, 
                        <a href="www.google.com">Singapre</a>.
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're only using opacity to hide the panel try `display:none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.accordion__item input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.panel {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 0;
    //opacity: 0; instead use display: none
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
            transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
```

Mark accepted answer, if you feel answer is coreect

Comment: Sorry, this does actually work. Thank you!!! Why did i need to make the change here?  I guess, when in checked state. Where as before, I only applied display none, to .panel class. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pointer-events`

```css
.accordion__item input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div.panel {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.panel {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```